# Повторный вывод строки, если при WHERE IN () есть повторяющиеся значения

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Существует ли запрос, который повторно выводит из таблицы БД строки, если они указываются несколько раз в условии?
Приведу пример.

```
$card_product = $pdo->query("SELECT under_service.id, under_service.title, under_service.link FROM under_service WHERE under_service.id IN (1,2,5,1,7,2)");
```

У меня есть запрос, который выводит услуги по id, но он выводит их только один раз и в порядке возрастания. Я понимаю, что он так и должен делать, но мне бы хотелось как-то сформировать таблицу в таком порядке как указано в IN (...). Существует ли какие-то способы это реализовать без создания таблиц? А если нет, то какие таблицы я должен создать (знаю, что должна будет быть связь многие ко многим, но так и не могу понять что именно объединять и выводить)

Использую phpmyadmin 4.7.9 10.1.31-MariaDB

Comment: Версию MySQL укажите... *Существует ли запрос* Да, конечно. *Я понимаю, что он так и должен делать* Один раз - да. В порядке возрастания - нет.

Comment: Добавьте это в вопрос, а не комментарием. *10.1.31-MariaDB* Хреново, СТЕ недоступны... максимальное количество элементов в списке - есть? или теоретически - неограничено?

Comment: _максимальное количество элементов в списке_ Вы имеете в виду список указанный в IN (...) ? Если так, то он может быть неограничен. Вместо данных значений у меня стоит переменная, которая хранит сформированный список id в зависимости от того, какие были выбраны пользователем

Comment: Тогда только преобразование списка в подзапрос.

Comment: Можете, пожалуйста, пояснить глупому?

Comment: Конвертируете список из того вида, который в IN, в тот вид, который указан в [ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/950202/229437), т.е. `SELECT 1 id, 1 sort UNION ALL SELECT 2,2 UNION ALL ... UNION ALL SELECT 2,6`, и используете это как подзапрос во FROM.

Answer (score 0):

Создаешь еще одну таблицу где будет только два поля

```
ID, SORT
1   1
2   2
5   3
1   4
7   5
2   6
```

Делаешь порядок сортировке в этой таблице.
В запросе объединяешь обе таблицы и делаешь сортировку
ORDER BY table2.sort